# Date variables within rsync filters?

Tags: linux, rsync, filter

I have an rsync script that syncs logs files from a remote server.  The log files are always named YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS.

At the moment, I have a filter in place to only get the current year's logs:

Filter:
- 2009*
- 2010*
- 2011*
- 2012*
+ 2013*

My question is this....if I only wanted to sync two months worth (current month and previous month), is there a way to use a variable in the script (i.e, + yearVariable-MonthVariable*) without having to update it constantly by hand?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `date` and it's calc functions to aid you:

```
date --date="1 months ago" +%Y-%m
```

will currently output `2013-03`. Store this in a var and use it to construct your filters.

```
pm=$(date --date="1 months ago" +%Y-%m)
cm=$(date +%Y-%m)

Filters in rsync string: -2012* +$cm +$pm
```

or something like that.

Comment: Perfect - thank you!  Do you know if I can do this directly in the rsync filter txt? (i.e, date1=date --date="1 months ago" +%Y-%m, date2=date +%Y-%m, + date1, + date2)

Comment: Yes, you can, but it's not a good idea IMHO, as the command gets unreadable quite fast.  Use variables like in my edit.

Comment: Thanks - your updated post just answered my question!  Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I just implemented this in my rsync filter but it still is trying to sync all of 2013.  Was wondering if you might be able to have a quick look and see what I'm doing wrong?  Thank you so much!  `PM=$(date --date="1 months ago" +Y%-%m)
CM=$(date +%Y-%m)

- 2009*
- 2010*
- 2011*
- 2012*
+ $PM*
+ $CM*`

Comment: Could you edit your complete rsync command into your question?